# Ways to compare search results in Sitecore 9.0.2

Tags: content-search, search-facet

I performed search of a particular item type with the Sitecore in-bulit search in the content Editor as i wanted to see some items that are modified by a particular user. I filtered by the template type and the facet "Author".

The issue is that i get different result count for the same search criteria for master DB and Web DB. I want to find the delta records.

Is there any way that i can export the search results in CSV and then compare or download the results from from DB and run a comparison on both?

Answer (score 1):

You will see the differences with the same search criteria for master DB and Web DB, because of the multiple version and workflow states in the master database. If you want to filter out the result based on the latest published version then you need to add new facets in the Sitecore - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/facets.html
But based on your requirement, my suggestion will be using Sitecore Powershell Extension, you can write your script to filter out the result and Show-ListView will give option to download the result in excel and other formats. see below sample script -

```
$path ="masterorweb:/sitecore/content/yourpath" 
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | 
        Where-Object { $_.TemplateId  -eq "YourTempalteID" -and $_."__Updated By" -eq 
"sitecore\YourUser" } 
$items |Show-ListView
```

You can also extend this script to compare the results from both databases and show only differences.